# MSSQL XML max function returns null

Tags: sql, xml, xpath, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlxml

In my transaction table, I have an XML column which contains some additional information about the transaction, e.g. how some prices in the transaction were calculated (for the *publisher* side and the *seller* side). Since the calculation algorithm may change, a transaction can be calculated multiple times. The complete calculation history is saved in the XML.

Now I want to have the revision number of the algorithm of the most recent calculation. The XML structure looks like this:

```xml
<DataItems>
    <!-- ... more data here ... -->
    <CalculationHistory>
        <Seller Revision="3" Time="2013-10-22T10:00:18.6294944Z" Result="20">
            <Step Index="0" NodeId="c3e33dd5-25e0-4272-8b6f-f65fb2f0659b">bla</Step>
            <Step Index="1" NodeId="b76b0915-7527-4df4-8185-5a425e723491">bla</Step>
            <Step Index="2" NodeId="7e51947e-85ef-431f-8a21-9f4e30136805">bla</Step>
            <Step Index="3" NodeId="10212fe9-8378-463d-b35b-27225b3cf2a1">bla</Step>
        </Seller>
        <Seller Revision="4" Time="2013-10-22T14:54:53.974548Z" Result="20">
            <Step Index="0" NodeId="c3e33dd5-25e0-4272-8b6f-f65fb2f0659b">bla</Step>
            <Step Index="1" NodeId="b76b0915-7527-4df4-8185-5a425e723491">bla</Step>
            <Step Index="2" NodeId="7e51947e-85ef-431f-8a21-9f4e30136805">bla</Step>
            <Step Index="3" NodeId="10212fe9-8378-463d-b35b-27225b3cf2a1">bla</Step>
        </Seller>
        <Publisher Revision="7" Time="2013-10-22T14:54:53.9794031Z" Result="40">
            <Step Index="0" NodeId="2ce85808-903f-40b0-b8a9-c72e02d36d71">bla</Step>
            <Step Index="1" NodeId="50ca67cc-5df8-450d-06d9-72c224027406">bla</Step>
            <Step Index="2" NodeId="b2122e9f-c15b-4fa8-ce22-3dc73933d3d3">bla</Step>
        </Publisher>
    </CalculationHistory>
</DataItems>
```

So what I tried is to select the most recent revision number as a column like this:

```sql
SELECT XmlColumn.value('(/DataItems/CalculationHistory/Seller[@Time = max(/DataItems/CalculationHistory/Seller/@Time)]/@Revision)[1]', 'int') AS SellerRevision FROM Transactions
```

But this returns `null` every time. I found out that the problem is the `max()` function returning `null` even in this case:

```sql
SELECT XmlColumn.query('max(/DataItems/CalculationHistory/Seller/@Time)') FROM Transactions
```

...although replacing `max` with `data` returns the correct timestamp(s).

So I guess I'm not using the `max` function correctly, but what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange, `max` doesn't work on string attributes/elements:

```
select (select cast('<A D="1"/>' as xml)).query('max(/A/@D)')
-- returns 1

select (select cast('<A D="a"/>' as xml)).query('max(/A/@D)')
-- returns nothing
```

some workaround could be using variable:

```
declare @Time nvarchar(max)

select @Time = max(T.C.value('@Time', 'nvarchar(max)'))
from @Data.nodes('DataItems/CalculationHistory/Seller') as T(C)

select @Data.value('(/DataItems/CalculationHistory/Seller[@Time=sql:variable("@Time")]/@Revision)[1]', 'int')
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/23566)</kbd>**

I'll try to check later if it's possible to use max on strings in SQL Server xpath

Comment: Your workaround works indeed, but it's (unavoidably) complicated especially because I have to use two of those queries in one statement in Entity Framework for .NET. Of course, your answer solves the problem - although I used another workaround where I restructured my C# code to allow a simpler query. (Now I check for existence of an XML node with a specific `Revision` attribute value.)